# Transfer data to BottomSheetScaffold, jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

The application has a data sheet, when you click on a sheet element, you need to open the BottomSheetScaffold, how do I transfer the data of the pressed element to it if the sheet itself (LazyColumn) is inside the BottomSheetScaffold?

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            BottomSheetContent()
        },
        sheetContainerColor = White,
        sheetDragHandle = sheetDragHandle,
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp
    ) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.background(color = Gray6)) {
            items(titleService) { title ->
                Text(
                    text = title.uppercase(), modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
.clickable { ??? },
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    fontFamily = TTNormsFontFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
                    color = Gray1
                )

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, your bottom sheet has to have a state for fields you want to show e.g you wanna show your data sheet's title in bottomSheet then you will have something like `val title by remember { mutableStateOf("") }` preferably at the outer most composable you have or even in your viewModel. Its called "state hoisting"  that state being at the outermost composable instead of being where it's used, and thus you will be able to do an assignment to your hoisted state object(`title`) in your data sheet's onClick method like below:

```
.clickable {  
    scope.launch {
       title = title //-> title in your lazy column's items block
       bottomSheetState.open()
}
```

then you will need to pass that title state to your BottomSheetContent:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    var title by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            BottomSheetContent(title)
        },
        sheetContainerColor = White,
        sheetDragHandle = sheetDragHandle,
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp
    ) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.background(color = Gray6)) {
            items(titleService) { title ->
                Text(
                    text = title.uppercase(), modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            scope.launch {
                                title = title //-> title in your lazy column's items block
                                bottomSheetState.open()
                            },
                        }
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                    fontFamily = TTNormsFontFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
                    color = Gray1
                )

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Note** : *This is a very basic state hoisting example and not very convenient most of the time. Best case scenario is getting events from UI and processing them in our ViewModel by updating our states as response to these events.*